# Google Analytics Measurement iOS Campaign Tracking Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

I'm just wondering how to find the web+app Property ID on Google Analytics.

Because I want to use iOS Campaign Tracking URL Builder.
When I tried to use that, I had to enter the Google Analytics Property ID as like UA-XXXX-Y, but I couldn't find the Property ID as the format.
On my team's google analytics app+web property tracks both of the apps(AOS, iOS) as well.

the problem is, the app+web property doesn't have UA-xxx format, just numbers.

however, the tracking URL builder wants to enter the type of above.

in this situation, what can I do for tacking iOS?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @AKADM?